# DNS lookup with JSON output

Tags: command-line, dns

The Bind related tools (`host`, `dig`, `nslookup`) don’t seem
to be capable of encoding their output as JSON, judging from the
man pages. I’m looking for a CLI tool that is, preferably one that
does not depend on an interpreter or language runtime.

(DOH is not an option as most DNS servers don’t support it.)

Comment: You can create json output via jq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470049/build-a-json-string-with-bash-variables

Comment: @Adil: I’m aware of that, it’s what I’m trying to avoid.

Comment: You will not find any utility that does not depend on an interpreter or on a language runtime.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but [ogham/dog: A command-line DNS client](https://github.com/ogham/dog) seems to support JSON output.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Could you turn that into an answer, it fits the bill exactly!

Comment: It doesn't satisfy "_one that does not depend on an interpreter or language runtime_" though

Comment: Being written in Rust, it only depends on the C library and is otherwise a static build. That’s definitely what I meant. (I didn’t mean the ELF interpreter if that is what you’re referring to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ogham/dog: A command-line DNS client](https://github.com/ogham/dog) has JSON output, as described in the section [Output options](https://github.com/ogham/dog#output-options):

```
-J, --json               Display the output as JSON
```

I haven't tried it myself yet. Possible caveats:

- at the time of writing (2021-06-14), there has been only the [initial release v0.1.0 (2020-11-07)](https://github.com/ogham/dog/releases/tag/v0.1.0), and there is no widespread distribution support yet.
- a statically compiled binary for x86-64 is available, [but unfortunately requires GLIBC_2.32](https://github.com/ogham/dog/issues/28). This limits it to very recent distributions; it won't run e.g. on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which has only GLIC_2.31.